# Most efficient way to find a record in Access linked to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a multi user Access UI linked to a SQL Server database that is used to perform loan reviews for a mortgage company.  Users are currently using the 'Find Record' function that already exists in Access and it takes a very long time to locate the record.  While I do understand why it takes so long and what it theoretically needs to do, I can't figure out the best way to write code to do directly to the record needed.  It needs to be a message box similar to the existing find record function, but that performs the most efficient way.  I tried the following, which doesn't include a message box, and it doesn't work:

```vb
  Private Sub txtFindLoan_AfterUpdate()

  Dim sSQL As String
  sSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_PreCloseAuditEnc WHERE LOAN_NUM = '" & 
  Me.txtFindLoan & "'"

  Me.RecordSource = sSQL
  Me.Requery
  End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ You should never receive input from the user and then directly execute that against any database.

Comment: Additionally, it may be worth exploring precisely where the bottleneck is.  Query tuning will only get you so far if there are no indexes or the server is a raspberry pi, etc.

Comment: What you have should work just fine. It not clear if LOAD_NUM is a text column, or a number column. Using all kinds of code, store procedures etc. it not really going to change much of anything here. In your example code is it assumed that dbo_PreCloseAuditEnc is a standard linked table? If there is 500, or 5,000,000 rows, what you have should work instant if an index on LOAD_NUM exists on sql server. Access will only pull the one record down the network pipe with your example. You should not need anything more then what you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bottleneck, except that you don't need a requery. And, of course, make sure you have an *index* on the LOAN_NUM field.

You could have an *InputBox* to pick up the loan number. The code could be called from a button:

```
Private Sub LoanButton_Click()

    Dim sLoanNo As String
    Dim sSQL As String

    sLoanNo = InputBox("Loan Number:", "Select Loan Number")
    If sLoanNo <> "" Then
        ' Input provided.
        ' Validate input. 
        ' IsValidLoanNumber will be a function to do this. Must return True/False.
        If IsValidLoanNumber(sLoanNo) Then
            sSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_PreCloseAuditEnc WHERE LOAN_NUM = '" & sLoanNo & "'"    
            Me.RecordSource = sSQL
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably off best using `ADODB` since you're only using external data, and binding the form directly to a filtered `ADODB` recordset.

As Sean Lange said, you should parameterize your query, and you can do that either using DAO or ADO, but not by modifying the `Me.RecordSource` property

```vb
Private Sub txtFindLoan_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sSQL As String
'I'm assuming your table name in MS SQL is dbo.PreCloseAuditEnc
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PreCloseAuditEnc WHERE LOAN_NUM = ?"
    Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection
'Enter a valid OLEDB connection string here:
    adoConn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = adoConn
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adChar, Value:=Me.txtFindLoan)
    Me.RecordSet = cmd.Execute
End Sub
```